# How to increase the delay on animation on every pass of a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jquery-animate, delay

First I've created a basic demonstration of what I have at the moment [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ybs76/).

Second this is the javascript I'm using.

```
var boxes = ["#one","#two","#three","#four"];

boxhover = function(a){
    $("#hover").hover(
        function(){
            $(a).stop(true).delay(250).animate({opacity:1});
        },
        function(){
            $(a).stop(true).delay(250).animate({opacity:0});
        }
    )
}

for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++)
{
    boxhover(boxes[i])
}
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to have each box hover one after the each other with a delay time of 250. I've tried adding a delay to the animation function (as you can see above) and also a setTimeout in the for loop, but no luck. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the array index as an additional parameter to your `boxhover` function and then perform a multiplication on the delay factor.

```
var boxes = ["#one","#two","#three","#four"];

boxhover = function(a, i){
    $("#hover").hover(
        function(){
            $(a).stop(true).delay(250 * i).animate({opacity:1});
        },
        function(){
            $(a).stop(true).delay(250 * i).animate({opacity:0});
        }
    )
}

for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++)
{
    boxhover(boxes[i], i)
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TtgvU/)

**Alternative Solution:**

To avoid binding multiple hover event handlers on `#hover` and having to maintain an array of IDs, you can do the following:

```
$("#hover").on({
    'mouseenter': function(e) {
        // Animate the box set to visible
        animateBoxSet(1);
    },
    'mouseleave': function(e) {
        // Animate the box set to invisible
        animateBoxSet(0);
    }
});

function animateBoxSet(opacity) {
    // For each box
    $('.box').each(function (index, element) {
        // Set the delay based on the index in the set
        var delay = 250 * index;
        // Animate it the visibility after the delay
        $(element).stop(true).delay(delay).animate({
            'opacity': opacity
        });
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UadnF/2/)

Comment: @user1846307 If you are interested, I also added an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, unfortunately the boxes were just a demo in my live problem I need to use an array. But I haven't seen the on() function before so I will look at using that in the future. Thanks again.